# Getting 'FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.' from onsnapshot error when user has the correct permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to create a document reference, set up an onsnapshot listener, save the document and then upload a file which will trigger a cloud function which will make updates to the document i am listening to. But `onSnapshot` gives a permissions error of `'FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.'` after the snapshot has run once (I guess for the initial state).

I have tried running simulations of accessing and writing the data in the firebase console and it works without any errors

```
const db = window.firebase.firestore()
const newBaseRef = db.collection('base').doc()

newBaseRef.onSnapshot(doc => {
  console.log('Current data: ', doc.data())
}, function (error) {
  throw error // THIS ALWAYS GETS HIT
})

newBaseRef.set({
  uid: window.firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
  createdAt: window.firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
})
```

here are my security rules

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /printset/{document=**} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    match /file/{document=**} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    match /base/{document=**} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I dont expect the error callback to run

Comment: Would help to also post your security rules.

Comment: Can you try with `match /base/{baseId}/{document=**}`. `match /base/{document==**}` should work. But i wonder. Also `.doc()` seems to be empty, Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes it is intentional as I wanted to set up the listener to receive the changes that the cloud function makes to the document. So i create the reference, set up the listener and then use .set to create the doc on the server. I can try your suggestion now.... update: the change to the security rules made no difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newBaseRef.set()` return `Promise`.

So when `newBaseRef.onSnapshot()` is called,  `newBaseRef.data().uid` doesn't set yet.

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set

You should call `newBaseRef.onSnapshot()` after `Promise.resolve()`.

```js
const db = window.firebase.firestore()
const newBaseRef = db.collection('base').doc()


newBaseRef.set({
  uid: window.firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
  createdAt: window.firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
}).then(() => {
  newBaseRef.onSnapshot(doc => {
    console.log('Current data: ', doc.data())
  }, function (error) {
    throw error // THIS ALWAYS GETS HIT
  })
})
```

And more.

If you want to only Insert then you should use `newBaseRef.add({})`.

If you want to Insert or DeleteInsert(Replace All Data) then you should use `newBaseRef.set({})`.

If you want to InsertUpdate or Update then you should use `newBaseRef.set({}, {merge, true})`.

If you want to only Update then you should use `newBaseRef.update({})`.

If you want to InsertUpdate or Update then change your security rules to the following setting.

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /printset/{document=**} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    match /file/{document=**} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    match /base/{document=**} {
      allow read, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid
      allow update: if resource == null || request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Im not sure what to take from your comment? What are you saying is wrong? I am trying to create a reference to a doc prior to submitting so that I can listen for changes. The document is getting created fine, but erroring on the listener for changes

Comment: to confirm, your security rules do not help

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I thought The error occurred at `newBaseRef.set()`. I edited my answer. Please check my answer again.